# Subjonctif après « j'espère que »

Tags: subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Selon mes livres on utilise habituellement l'indicatif après « espérer que ».

Mon ami m'a dit que, bien qu'on dise

> j'espère que tu viens

on dit aussi

> j'espère que tu puisses venir.

Il n'a jamais donné une règle pour expliquer la différence. Est-ce que vous pourriez expliquer cette construction ?

(n.b. Il ne s'agit pas de la conjugaison de ces verbes, mais c'est une question d'usage : pourquoi utilise-on le subjonctif avec *pouvoir* mais l'indicatif avec *venir*, en ces exemples ?)

Comment: Après _espérer_, j'ai l'impression que je met plutôt l'indicatif (et je n'ai pas vu d'exemple dans le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/esperer) avec le subjonctif).  J'utiliserais donc _pourras_ et pas _puisses_.  J'ai cependant la vague impression qu'il y a des contextes ou le subjonctif est possible ou obligatoire.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je ne comprends pas la phrase :

> *j'espère que tu puisses venir.

où je ne trouve pas l'emploi du subjonctif justifié.

Après *espérer*, comme après tous les verbes « d'opinion ou de perception » on met dans la subordonnée introduite par que :

> L'indicatif toutes les fois que l'on considère la réalité d'un fait ; le conditionnel quand on exprime un fait éventuel, hypothétique.
>   [...]
>   Le subjonctif lorsque le verbe subordonné exprime un fait simplement envisagé dans l'esprit, et non situé sur le plan de la réalité. Le cas se rencontre notamment après une principale négative, interrogative ou conditionnelle, ou encore quand le verbe principal se colore d'une nuance affective ou quand il implique la négation, le doute, l'incertitude [...]  (Grevisse, *Le bon usage*, 2<sup>e</sup>édition, 1975)

Dans le langage courant je proposerai :

- J'espère que tu pourras venir.
- J'espérais que tu pourrais venir.
- Je n'espère pas que tu puisses venir.
- Je n'espère pas que tu pourras venir.
- Espères-tu qu'il puisse venir ?
- Espères-tu qu'il pourra venir ?

Dans son chapitre sur les verbes d'opinion et de perception Grevisse consacre à *espérer que* toute une page que je résume ainsi :

*Espérer que* est suivi de l'indicatif (du conditionnel si la subordonnée exprime un fait hypothétique ou éventuel) ; dans l'emploi négatif ou interrogatif, ordinairement il est suivi du subjonctif.
On peut trouver le subjonctif après *espérer que* pris affirmativement, alors le verbe est « chargé d'affectivité ». Grevisse donne des exemples qui sonnent tous très littéraires, dont un seul avec *espérer* au présent de l'indicatif :

> Il dénie tout réalisme à ceux qui espèrent que son redressement puisse être obtenu par l’enthousiasme d’un quatre Août. (Giraudoux, *Sans pouvoirs*, p. 10)

Grevisse fait remarquer que *désespérer que* et *se désespérer que* veulent toujours le subjonctif :

> Je désespère que cette affaire réussisse.

Je signale deux lectures liées à la question et qui font référence à Grevisse :

- [L'exemple du subjonctif en FLE](http://books.google.fr/books?id=l93qxQlISlEC&pg=PA154&dq=%22verbes%20d%27opinion%20et%20de%20perception%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=GDslVPPyG-3d7QbT8YD4DA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22verbes%20d%27opinion%20et%20de%20perception%22&f=false), par Marie-Eve Damar (linguiste)
- [Comment se construit le verbe « espérer » ?](http://la-grammaire-de-forator.over-blog.fr/article-comment-se-construit-le-verbe-esperer-54165791.html) sur un blog de grammaire.

Comment: Une très bonne réponse! Tellement informative :)

Comment: Cette réponse est très informative si on se borne à une description purement normative...!

Answer (score 2):

À mon avis, le subjonctif s'entend relativement souvent après *espérer que*, même s'il est proscrit par les livres de référence. La raison en est que son sens se rapproche beaucoup d'un verbe de volonté comme *désirer* ou *souhaiter*. D'ailleurs, d'autres langues romanes telles que l'espagnol utilisent normalement le subjonctif après ce verbe pour cette raison-là.

Selon cette grammaire: http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/677.html , on peut rencontrer le subjonctif après *espérer que* employé à l'impératif.