# Espérer plus subjonctif : pourquoi pas ?

Tags: subjonctif, subordonnées

> II/ Au subjonctif : le subjonctif est utilisé pour un fait envisagé
>   mais non encore réel ni effectif.
>
> 1- Après les verbes de volonté: vouloir- exiger - désirer - souhaiter
>
> (...)
>
> Elle veut qu'on lui rende sa nouvelle poupée.
>
> **Attention : le verbe espérer, bien qu'il soit un verbe de volonté,
>   exige l'indicatif**
>
> Sa mère espère qu'il dort profondément.

[Référence : https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-93819.php ]

Pourquoi le verbe espérer ne fait pas partie d'autres verbes ? Y a-t-il une explication logique ?

Quand pourrait-on dire (si l'on peut le faire)

> Sa mère espère qu'il dorme profondément.

?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Merci ; je viens de rajouter la source de cet extrait. C'est pas moi qui l'ai écrit:-)! Du coup, pourquoi préfères-tu donner ça comme commentaire au lieu de réponse ?

Comment: Oui, je me suis rendu compte que j'avais commencé à répondre, en plus de la remarque sur la règle donnée. J'étais en train de transformer ça en réponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Sa mère espère tous les jours qu'il dorme profondément » est tout à fait possible. Dire que espérer « exige l'indicatif » n'est pas correct, même si c'est l'indicatif que l'on emploie dans la majorité des cas. Lorsqu'on emploie *espérer* pour le moment présent, il s'agit d'un questionnement, et le mode subjonctif n'est pas approprié. Il est question de la véracité du fait, on ne fait pas que le mentionner.

J'écris ça pour tenter de montrer qu'espérer sur l'instant et espérer dans un contexte, sont deux emplois que l'on peut distinguer. Mais le choix du mode étant principalement une question d'usage, chercher une explication « logique » n'est pas vraiment possible.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. Est-ce que tu as une idée pourquoi les livres (du moins ceux que je possède) de grammaire du français (pas les bibles comme le Bon Usage:-)!) n'en parlent pas ? Et si j'exagère en disant que les livres n'en parlent par, pourquoi cet article affirme  Attention : le verbe espérer, bien qu'il soit un verbe de volonté, exige l'indicatif ? Si c'était une question fermée (QCM), par exemple : Sa mère espère qu'il ...profondément et un étudiant choisissait le subjonctif serait-il pénalisé ? Qu'en penses-tu ?

Comment: Sans le « tous les jours », ou une indication temporelle similaire qui montre que c'est une aspiration, l'indicatif est le seul possible. Je cherche des emplois dans la littérature avec le subjonctif, et j'en trouve principalement lorsque espérer est à l'imparfait, mais tout de même, très peu.

Comment: J'ai trouvé une vieille question similaire : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/subjonctif-apr%c3%a8s-jesp%c3%a8re-que?rq=1 (@Stéphae Gimenez)