Futur, conditionnel ou subjonctif ?
Laquelle de ces trois phrases est correcte ?

j'espère que vous tiendrez votre promesse.
j'espère que vous teniez votre promesse.
j'espère que vous tiendriez votre promesse.

Si quelqu'un peut m'éclaircir je serai très reconnaissant, et si les trois sont correctes c'est quoi la différence ?

Seule la première phrase est correcte. L'indicatif est le mode le plus souvent utilisé après espérer que.
On peut modifier les deux autres comme ceci :

J'aimerais que vous teniez votre promesse. (subjonctif après aimer que)


J'espérais que vous tiendriez votre promesse. (mais ce n'a pas été le cas)


L'indicatif après espérer? Il faut que je révise quels verbes veulent le subjonctift... Ceci dit, je n'arrive pas à mettre un subjonctif, si j'essaie quelques phrases au hasard.

@Frank Espérons qu'il ne tienne pas sa promesse.

Donc, c'est dans la gray zone où le subjonctif est de moins en moins utilisé (et appris, apparemment).

@Frank Le hasard ne marche pas ici. C'est  les chances de réalisation qu'on veut exprimer.  https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/esperer-que-subjonctif/ ; https://www.grevisse.fr/le-blog-chroniques-grevisse/norme-et-usage/souhaiter-esperer.

@Frank Et sur FL : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34350/358 ; Subjonctif après « j'espère que » et d'autres...
