# Espérer et désespérer (indicatif/subjonctif)

Tags: subjonctif, antonyme

> Je n'espère pas que cette affaire réussira.
>
> Je désespère que cette affaire réussisse.

Quelle est la différence entre la première et la deuxième phrase ?

Pourquoi **désespérer que** se construit avec le subjonctif ?

Questions connexes :

[Espérer plus subjonctif : pourquoi pas ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/esp%c3%a9rer-plus-subjonctif-pourquoi-pas?rq=1)

[Subjonctif après « j'espère que »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/subjonctif-apr%c3%a8s-jesp%c3%a8re-que?rq=1)

Comment: Il me semble qu'il y a déjà cette question : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11953/17649

Comment: @LPH Oui ma question mentionne cette question. Ma question porte sur désespérer :-)!

Comment: La réponse pour « désespérer que » est dans la réponse de user **Laure** à cette question : toujours le subjonctif ; le pourquoi n'est pas mentionné, cependant.

Comment: @LPH Oh; je m'excuse. Je ne l'ai pas vue.

Comment: Pas grave ; de toute façon il manque une explication que voilà en dans ma réponse, tirée de Grevisse.

Comment: L'explication y figure :  « Le subjonctif exprime un fait simplement envisagé dans l'esprit, et non situé sur le plan de la réalité ». Ensuite il suffit de saisir le sens de *désespérer*.

Comment: @Laure Il me semble que la raison spécifique pour « désespérer » soit sous le « d) », que je cite ci-dessous.

Comment: @LPH Ce que tu écris est exactement la même chose que [« Après espérer, comme après tous les verbes « d'opinion ou de perception » on met dans la subordonnée introduite par que :...Le subjonctif lorsque le verbe subordonné exprime un fait simplement envisagé dans l'esprit, et non situé sur le plan de la réalité.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/subjonctif-apr%c3%a8s-jesp%c3%a8re-que?rq=1)

Comment: @Laure Non, ce n'est pas la même chose : dans les termes de *Grevisse* au paragraphe « d) », « Le support exprime un sentiment (joie, tristesse, crainte, regret, admiration, étonnement, etc.) » ; c'est cela qui s'applique spécifiquement à « désespérer ». Il n'est pas question d'opinion et de perception mais de sentiments.

Comment: Par définition, le subjonctif exprime un souhait ou un espoir. Donc, il n'aurait pas de sens avec désespérer. En général, on désespère au présent, pas au futur.

Comment: "exprime un sentiment (joie, tristesse, crainte, regret, admiration, étonnement, etc." = = "tous les verbes d'opinion ou de **perception**" C'est idem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quelle est la différence entre la première et la deuxième phrase ?

> 1 - Je n'espère pas que cette affaire réussira.
>   2 - Je désespère que cette affaire réussisse.

1 - Tu ne souhaites pas la réussite de l'affaire.

2 - Tu voudrais que l'affaire réussisse mais tu doutes énormément d'une issue satisfaisante et tu crains beaucoup qu'elle ne réussisse pas

Quand à pourquoi on emploie l'indicatif dans la 1 et le subjonctif dans la 2 c'est écrit dans la réponse qui figure [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11955/358) :

1 - indicatif parce que tu [considères la réalité du fait](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/subjonctif-apr%C3%A8s-jesp%C3%A8re-que?rq=1).

2 - subjonctif parce que désespérer est un verbe exprimant un sentiment et que [« on met le subjonctif dans la subordonnée introduite par que après les verbes d'opinion ou de perception quand le fait est simplement envisagé dans l'esprit, et non situé sur le plan de la réalité. »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/subjonctif-apr%C3%A8s-jesp%C3%A8re-que?rq=1) Par définition quand on désespère de quelque chose on n'est pas sur le plan de la réalité.

Comment: Merci. Donc Je n'espère pas que cette affaire réussira = J'espère que cette affaire ne réussira pas, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @Dimitris Oui. J'ai recopié ce que j'avais écrit dans une autre réponse ce qui à mon avis était tout à fait inutile. J'ai failli demander la fermeture de ta question. En fait tout ce que tu demandais c'était le sens des phrases.

Comment: Peut-on comprendre "je n'espère pas que cette affaire réussira" dans le sens littéral de "même si j'aimerais bien, je ne l'espère pas car il y a peu de chance, je ne suis pas dupe", ou est-ce que justement ce serait l'emploi du subjonctif qui traduirait cela : "Je n'espère pas que cette affaire réussisse" ? Car pour moi on dirait plutôt "j'espère que cette affaire ne réussira pas" pour exprimer qu'on ne souhaite pas qu'elle réussisse.

Comment: @Destal Première partie : moi je ne le comprends pas comme ça mais je comprends qu'on puisse le comprendre ainsi. La sutie : Pour moi "j'espère que cette affaire ne réussira pas" veut dire "je ne souhaite pas qu'elle réussisse. Je viens de m'apercevoir qu'[une partie de ma réponse avait disparu](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/40122/1) quand j'ai recopié mon autre réponse. Mais le PO avait lu la première version....

Answer (score 1):

Le pourquoi est expliqué dans *Grevisse* ; je le recopie ci-dessous.

> (Grevisse) Le subjonctif est employé quand le locuteur ne s'engage pas sur
>   la réalité du fait, et notamment dans les cas suivants (a), b), c), d), …).
>
> d) Le support exprime un sentiment (joie, tristesse, crainte,
>   regret, admiration, étonnement, etc.).
>   Propositions introduites par que.
>
> - Je me désespérais qu'une façon
>     d'être ému, que j'avais entrevue, me FÛT irrémédiablement fermée.

À la différence de « espérer », le verbe « désespérer » doit être considéré comme étant un verbe qui exprime un sentiment. Cela se déduit de la définition du verbe dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9rer) (B. 2.).

> B.− Emploi trans. Contrarier vivement, affliger, tourmenter.

Cela montre que « désespérer » n'a pas le sens de « ne pas espérer », d'où  la raison pour ne pas l'assimiler à « désespérer » dans la question du mode à utiliser. Cependant, de toute façon, lorsque « espérer que » se trouve dans une forme négative il faut employer le subjonctif (https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11955/17649) (réponse par user **Laure**).

Comment: Merci. Ma question comporte aussi cela : "Quelle est la différence entre la première et la deuxième phrase ? " (portant sur je n'espère pas que et je désespère que)